# ToggleButton controlling PopUp window control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox, popupwindow

I have a PopUp control being controlled by a `ToggleButton`. This works fine, however i do not like the appearence of the `ToggleButton` so I have applied a control template to make the `ToggleButton` look like a `CheckBox`. I would like the `CheckBox` to be checked when the PopUp is visible, and become unchecked when the PopUp window disappears. My current code is as follows, but I am not getting the desired effect.

```
    <ToggleButton x:Name="LegendToggleButton" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
        IsChecked="{Binding IsOpen, ElementName=LegendPopup, mode=OneWayToSource}">
        <ToggleButton.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                <CheckBox x:Name="LegendCheckBox" Content="Show Legend" Style="{StaticResource {x:Type CheckBox}}" 
                          IsChecked="{Binding IsOpen, ElementName=LegendPopup, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ToggleButton.Template>
    </ToggleButton>

    <Popup x:Name="LegendPopup"
           PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=LegendToggleButton}"
           Placement="Top"
           PopupAnimation="Fade"
           StaysOpen="False">
```

This works fine in terms of making the window appear when the toggle button is clicked (with the `CheckBox` becoming checked, and then unchecking and hiding the popup when other controls are clicked. However, if i show the PopUp by clicking the toggle button, and then click the toggle button again (which i would expect to hide the popup), the popup momentarily closses and then straight away reappears.

Comment: Without knowing what you actually see, and what you were expecting to see, I will take a wild guess: Whenever you change the control template, you need to start completely from scratch. The best way to change the look and feel of a control, is to go and copy/paste the style and template from MSDN, and change what you need: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296245%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come up with a solution, slightly different from the question i originally asked but the following code provides the functionality i was looking for. The method involves binding both the `CheckBox` `IsChecked` and the PopUp `IsOpen` property to the same bool on the viewmodel, and also setting this bool to false when the `CheckBox` loses focus (to hide the window and update the `CheckBox` checked property).

- XAML:

  ```
  <Popup x:Name="LegendPopup"
         PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=LegendToggleButton}"
         Placement="Top"
         PopupAnimation="Fade"
         StaysOpen="False"
         IsOpen="{Binding ShowLegendPopup, Mode=OneWay}"
           >
  ```
- c# Viewmodel

  ```
  private bool _showLegendPopup;
  public bool ShowLegendPopup
  {
      get
      {
          return _showLegendPopup;
      } 
      set
      {
          _showLegendPopup = value;
          OnPropertyChanged();
      }
  }

  public ICommand PopupClosingCommand { get; private set; }

  private void InitialiseCommands()
  {
      PopupClosingCommand =  new DelegatingCommand(PopupClosing);
  }

  private void PopupClosing()
  {
      ShowLegendPopup = false;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want a `ToggleButton` to look like a `CheckBox` instead of just using a `Checkbox`? The following code works like a charm:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="CheckBox" Content="Check me to open popup" />
<Popup IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=CheckBox, Path=IsChecked}">
    <Border Background="Silver" Padding="10">
        <TextBlock Text="Hello" />
    </Border>
</Popup>
```

If you really want to go with your solution, you should provide a "proper" template as sondergard suggested in his comment. I'm not quite sure if you can just nest a `CheckBox` as the only element in the Control Template of a `ToggleButton`. The least thing I would do is to establish `TemplateBinding` between the `CheckBox.IsChecked` and the `ToggleButton.IsChecked` property so that both of them are in sync. This might also be the thing that causes the odd behavior because you actually have two bindings to the popup that can update its `IsOpen` property (one on the `ToggleButton`, one on the `CheckBox` in the Control Template).

Comment: I tried this originally, although i believe that if you set the staysOpen property of the popup to false, the checkbox remains checked when the popup is not actually open, and it was this behaviour i was trying to eliminate.

Answer (score 0):

```
IsChecked="{Binding IsOpen, ElementName=LegendPopup, mode=OneWayToSource}"

IsChecked="{Binding IsOpen, ElementName=LegendPopup, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

if I'm correct these are the culprit..

It's actually changing the IsChecked value two times at once..